# How do I add an attribute to an Elasticsearch node for the purpose of Shard Allocation Filtering?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to follow the [reference guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/index-modules-allocation.html#shard-allocation-filtering) to make sure certain indexes end up on certain machines. I'm attempting to give 2 of my nodes an attribute named "storage_type", where one node gets "long_term" and one gets "short_term".

I understand that I need to add the attribute of "storage_type" to each of the nodes, and then set each index to have `{"index.routing.allocation.require.tag" : "short"}` or `{"index.routing.allocation.require.tag" : "long"}` respectively.

I've attempted to add these settings via `curl` calls, like most ES things, but it does not appear that I could `PUT` settings. i.e.:

```
 curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_nodes/my_node_name/_settings -d '{"storage_term" : "short_term"}'
```

So how do I add these attributes such as "storage_type" (which is n to nodes)? Is it a config file? A command line argument? An HTTP call that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not to be done through `curl` calls. You need to use `elasticsearch.yml`.

- in `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
node.storage_term: short_term
```

Answer (score 6):

Since version `5.0` node attributes are to be set via **`node.attr.`**:

```
node.attr.storage_term: short_term
```

See [Shard Allocation Filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/shard-allocation-filtering.html) section of the official reference.